# Can applications be downloaded without a Google Account and without disabling security features?

Tags: applications, security, installation, side-loading

If I wish to install applications such as Skype, DropBox, etc however without registering for a Google account, is that possible? If so, how do I install them without a Google account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ADB to install the applications.

Install the Android sdk ( https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html ).

Enable USB debugging in Settings>Applications>Development.
This process can be done even without enabling side-loading of apps. Open a command prompt window and type:

```
adb install app_name.apk
```

Comment: Thanks Ruben Roy. Do I have to disable any security features such as Installation of Non-market apps?

Comment: no you dont have to

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: you only need to have non market apps install enabled while installing them. You can disable it again once you've finished installing. Enabling USB debugging is a much bigger issue security wise than enabling non market app install.

Answer (score 3):

You could use other App stores like [**Amazon App Store**](http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/get-appstore/android) or **GetJar**, but you would also need accounts on those.

You can side-load apps via downloading APK files on PC and then installing them from your SD card. Just try opening the APK files with a file manager like **ES File Explorer** or **ASTRO File Manager** which would give a option to open it with Package manager or Install.

But I assume from your question that you don't want to enable **Installation of Non-market apps**, then you don't get much choice. Even Amazon App store requires that feature enabled.

Answer (score 0):

one can download APK files available on Google Play Store, without a Google account, by using [APK Pure](http://apkpure.com).
it also allows downloading previous versions which may be helpful for people trying older devices, which need older app version for compatibility reasons.

additionally, one may choose to use a region-specific build.